# OpenXML table copy gives OpenXmlUnknownElement

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I'm using OpenXML SDK with Word to produce labels. The base Word doc has one page with a table, two rows and two cells where each cell represents one label. My plan was to add pages as needed based on the size of a SQL result set. The append of the page works but the count of tables in the Body doesn't change. Is there a way to refresh the Element array? I suppose I can get the size of the result set and append the required number of pages then close and reopen the doc but I'm guessing I'm missing something simple.

**Reported the wrong problem** sorry, the doc looked correct in Word but not in the productivity tool. I updated the code to show my latest attempt. iTest now reports the correct number of tables but in the productivity tool the added tables are flagged as *OpenXmlUnknownElement*.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pages; ++i)
{
    Table table = new Table(doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Table>().First().CloneNode(true));
    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(table);
}
int iTest = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Table>().Count();
```

the xml shows there is an extra `<w:tbl>` generated:

```
<w:tbl xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:tbl>
    <w:tblPr>
      <w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid" />
```

So the real question is, how to copy and paste a table with OpenXML SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

new and CloneNode were redundant, also InsertAfter wasn't necessary but kept the tables together. Since I'm not updating the labels until later inserting after First() works for my purpose.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pages; ++i)
{
    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Table>().First().CloneNode(true), MDP.Document.Body.Elements<Table>().First());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Descendants<Table>` instead of `Elements<Table>`.

Also post the XML of your Body, so we can better help you.